# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {Owner1, Owner2, Owner3})

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am trying to get and display previousOwners, which is an array of objects in the MongoDB schema. I have listed the type as "Array" in the schema and have attempted iterating over the items in the carList.js file. I am unfortunately receiving the following error message:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {Owner1, Owner2, Owner3}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

```
react-dom.development.js:13231 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {Owner1, Owner2, Owner3}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    at throwOnInvalidObjectType (react-dom.development.js:13231)
    at createChild (react-dom.development.js:13469)
    at reconcileChildrenArray (react-dom.development.js:13719)
    at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:14125)
    at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:16990)
    at updateHostComponent (react-dom.development.js:17632)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19080)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:22670)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22293)
    at react-dom.development.js:11327
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11322)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11309)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21893)
    at dispatchAction (react-dom.development.js:16139)
    at carList.js:35
```

```
index.js:2178 The above error occurred in the <td> component:

    at td
    at tr
    at Car (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:80229:13)
    at tbody
    at table
    at div
    at CarList (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:80302:74)
    at div
    at div
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {Owner1, Owner2, Owner3}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    at throwOnInvalidObjectType (react-dom.development.js:13231)
    at createChild (react-dom.development.js:13469)
    at reconcileChildrenArray (react-dom.development.js:13719)
    at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:14125)
    at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:16990)
    at updateHostComponent (react-dom.development.js:17632)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19080)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:22670)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22293)
    at react-dom.development.js:11327
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11322)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11309)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21893)
    at dispatchAction (react-dom.development.js:16139)
    at carList.js:35
```

My code is as follows:

- Server: carsModel.js:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const carSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  Model: {
    type: String,
  },
  Make: {
    type: String,
  },
  Owner: {
    type: String,
  },
  Registration: {
    type: String,
  },
  Address: {
    type: String,
  },
  previousOwners: {
    type: Array,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Cars", carSchema);
```

- Client: carList.js:

```
const Car = (props) => (
  <tr>
    <td>{props.car._id}</td>
    <td>{props.car.Model}</td>
    <td>{props.car.Make}</td>
    <td>{props.car.Registration}</td>
    <td>{props.car.Owner}</td>
    <td>{props.car.Address}</td>
    <td>{props.car.previousOwners}</td>
  </tr>
);
```

Please see here the link to the GitHub repository: https://github.com/ChanBos/MERN-Cars-Database-Application

Comment: check the types of everything you're trying to render, make sure that they're not Objects

Comment: Based on the error `found: object with keys {Owner1, Owner2, Owner3}` and the `previousOwners` schema type being array, I think it's clear what is happening here.

Comment: @RameshReddy and Drew Reese Thank you for your assistance with this matter. I appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on what Drew Reese is alluding to...

#### Problem

React won't render arrays with structure.

For example:

```js
const cars = [
  {
    _id: 1,
    Model: "Toyota",
    Make: "Tundra",
    Registration: "January 1st, 1970",
    Owner: "Owner 3",
    Address: "123 Example Street",
    previousOwners: [{ name: "Owner1" }, { name: "Owner2" }]
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    Model: "Toyota",
    Make: "Tacoma",
    Registration: "January 1st, 1970",
    Owner: "Owner 6",
    Address: "123 Example Street",
    previousOwners: [{ name: "Owner4" }, { name: "Owner5" }]
  }
];
```

Instead, you'll have handle the layout for **all** arrays.

#### Solution

Change your [CarList](https://github.com/ChanBos/MERN-Cars-Database-Application/blob/master/client/src/components/carList.js) component to handle the `previousOwners` array (assuming it's an array of objects) similar to how you're handling/mapping the `car` array:

```js
// Imported react libraries and hooks.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
// Requiring Axios.
import axios from "axios";

/**
 * @param {*} props _id, Model, Make, Registration, Owner and Address.
 * @returns A table that displays all of the above mentioned information from the database.
 */

// Using object destructuring, destructure the car properties that will be rendered for the table output
const Car = ({ 
  _id, 
  Model, 
  Make, 
  Registration, 
  Owner, 
  Address, 
  previousOwners
}) => (
  <tr>
    <td>{_id}</td>
    <td>{Model}</td>
    <td>{Make}</td>
    <td>{Registration}</td>
    <td>{Owner}</td>
    <td>{Address}</td>
    {/* Change this next line to handle your previousOwners structure */}
    <td>{previousOwners.map(({ name }) => name).join(", ")}</td>
  </tr>
);

// Set the initial state of cars.
const CarList = () => {
  const [cars, setCars] = useState([]);

  // Utilized the useEffect() hook to get/ read the information from the database and respond displaying the data. If an error occurs the error
  // will be logged to console.
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("/cars/")
      .then((res) => {
        const data = res.data;
        setCars(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="listcontainer">
      <h6>Car List</h6>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr className="theaderrow">
            <th id="th-cell-left">ID</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Make</th>
            <th>Registration</th>
            <th>Owner</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th id="th-cell-right">Previous Owners</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{cars.map(car => <Car key={car._id} {...car} />)}</tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

// Exported CarList to App.js.
export default CarList;
```

#### Demo

[image: Edit Displaying Data]

#### Further Explanation

The `Car` component uses [object destructuring](https://www.javatpoint.com/es6-object-destructuring) to avoid using `props.car.Property`.

This line:
`<tbody>{cars.map(car => <Car key={car._id} {...car} />)}</tbody>`

Means map over the `cars` array and for each `car` [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) its properties into the `Car` component

This line:

`<td>{previousOwners.map(({ name }) => name).join(", ")}</td>`

Means map over the `previousOwners` array and just return the `name` property as a flatten array of strings:

`["Owner1, "Owner2"]`

Then `join` the array of strings with a comma and space(`,` ):

`Owner1, Owner2`

Comment: My sincerest apologies for the delayed response. I decided to step back from this task and to continue with another in the meantime. Sometimes it is better to hit the reset button. Thank you very much for your advice. I really appreciate the thorough explanation and the additional resources.